# populateViewHolder() isn't getting executed in a FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

My `RecyclerView` was working until I decided to start adding Tab Slide layout, so I moved it along with it's Viewholder to a `Fragment` class.

However, proved by debugging, the method `populateViewHolder()` isn't getting called. Here's my `Fragment`'s `onCreate()`:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //region RecyclerView
    View v = View.inflate(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.activity_recent_occasions,null);
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Campaigns");
    RecyclerView list = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Campaign,CampaignHolder>(Campaign.class,R.layout.recyclerview_template,CampaignHolder.class,ref) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(CampaignHolder viewHolder, Campaign model, int position) {
            viewHolder.setTitle(model.title);
            viewHolder.setDescription(model.description);
            viewHolder.setAuthor(model.author);
            viewHolder.setImage(model.image,getApplicationContext(),RecentOccasions.this);
        }
    };
    list.addItemDecoration(new HorizontalDividerItemDecoration.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build());
    list.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    //endregion

}
```

My model:

```
public class Campaign {
public String title;
public String description;
public String image;
public String author;

public Campaign() {
}
public Campaign(String title, String description, String image, String author) {
    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;
    this.image = image;
    this.author = author;
  }

}
```

---

**What I've tried**: Everything [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38263758/populateviewholder-not-executing-with-firebaserecycleradapter-android) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37876904/android-firebaserecycleradapter-populateviewholder-never-get-called)

Comment: did u get a solution?

Comment: @MRX Yeah, but I forgot it... It's been some time, let me see

Comment: Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: @MRX you have the same problem?

Comment: yes - i asked the question . Please see the comments aswell .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38709426/firebase-populateviewholder-is-never-called

Comment: you got it working @MRX Please help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39268663/firebaserecycleradapter-populateviewholder-is-not-populating-the-data-for-firs

Comment: @Abappletic Any Help, facing the same issue

Comment: @user1624194 I'm not sure how I fixed it, this was 2 months ago. I think it was an incorrect `DatabaseReference`